# i need to access images from gallery and then access the pixels of the image for further processing in android

Tags: android, image, android-image, android-gallery

this is the code i'm using currently,the code only displays the image from gallery. but i want to access the pixels of the image.i am confused exactly where the image data is stored in the code as in which variable.

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with 'pixels'

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314198/how-to-get-pixels-of-an-image-in-res-folder-of-an-android-project/13314444#13314444), here is described to get `Pixels`, you should use:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

and then :

```
bm.getPixel(x,y);// will return an int that corresponds to an int in the Color class, such as Color.BLACK or Color.WHITE.
```

Hope this may help you